# Ionic class context gone after callback

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, callback, ionic3

I'm trying to add the [seamless payment integration](https://document-center.wirecard.com/display/PTD/Seamless+integration) method of Wirecard into my Ionic 3 application. After the form is created, a callback method (`this.formCreated`) is called.

There is some logic that needs to be done there, but for now its only purpose is to dismiss the loading animation.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Loading, LoadingController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { PaymentService } from '../../providers/payment';

declare var WirecardPaymentPage;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-payment-add-creditcard',
  templateUrl: 'payment-add-creditcard.html'
})
export class PaymentAddCreditcardPage {
  public loader: Loading;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private paymentService: PaymentService,
              private translateService: TranslateService,
              private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    console.log('PaymentAddCreditcardPage');
    this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create();
    this.loader.present();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let requestData = this.paymentService.generateCreditCardRequest();
    WirecardPaymentPage.seamlessChangeLocale(this.translateService.currentLang);
    WirecardPaymentPage.seamlessRenderForm({
      requestData: requestData,
      wrappingDivId: 'wirecard-cc-target',
      onSuccess: this.formCreated,
      onError: this.processErrorResult
    });
  }

  formCreated(data) {
    this.loader.dismiss();
    console.log(data);
  }

  processErrorResult(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }

}
```

When testing this, it got this error:

```
Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined
```

I figured, that also other variables are undefined, so I guess the class context is gone.

So now I'm a bit lost. How do I get my context back or is there another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `onSuccess: this.formCreated,`, you are passing a reference of the function as a callback. The `this` inside this function will vary based on where this function is called from. To ensure that the `this` always refers to your current class, you can do something like this which will make sure that `formCreated` is always called with `PaymentAddCreditcardPage` instance as `this`:

```
onSuccess: (data) => this.formCreated(data),
```

---

Another option you can do is use `Function.bind` to explicitly specify the context:

```
onSuccess: this.formCreated.bind(this)
```

But be careful when using `Function.bind` in TypeScript, the resulting function will be untyped. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212

Comment: Thx, I just found the solution myself in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback
But you've been lightning fast ;)
So using `onSuccess: (data) => this.formCreated(data),` did the trick.